# Asynchronous call of mongojs find function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongojs

I have one mongojs query such as:

```
db.mapping.find(
    { "provider":req.params.provider, "perId":mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.perId) },
    function(err, que){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        else if(que)
        {
            totalVideoList = [];

            for (var i=0; i < que.length; i++)
            {
                myid = que[i].providerId;

                db.ABC.find({}, function(err, que1){
                    if(err)
                        res.send(err);

                    var x = {};
                    for (var j=0; j < que1.length; j++)
                    {
                        searching(que1[j]);
                    }

                    videoList = [];
                    getVideo(requiredDocument);

                    totalVideoList = totalVideoList.concat(videoList);

                });
            }
            res.json(totalVideoList);

        }
        else
            res.json([]);
    });
```

Currently I am always getting [] (empty array) as my response. The problem is due asynchronous nature of callback function of mongojs. Before the expected output comes in "totalVideoList" variable, it responds us with totalVideoList = [].
I don't know how to use async.each() here. Please help me to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
db.mapping.find(
    { "provider":req.params.provider, "perId":mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.perId) },
    function(err, que){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        else if(que)
        {
            totalVideoList = [];

            async.each(que, function(item, callback){
              myid = item.providerId;

                db.ABC.find({}, function(err, item){
                    if(err)
                        return callback(err);

                    var x = {};
                    for (var j=0; j < item.length; j++)
                    {
                        searching(item[j]);
                    }

                    videoList = [];
                    getVideo(requiredDocument);

                    totalVideoList = totalVideoList.concat(videoList);
                    callback(null);

                });
            }, function(asyncErr){
              if(asyncErr)
                 return resp.json(asyncErr);
                 resp.json(totalVideoList);
            });            
        }
        else
            res.json([]);
    });
```

Comment: I am getting repeated result of first item of outer query in totalVideoList. I think this is due to the fact that you placed the res.json(totalVideoList)  inside async.each() function.  But when i placed it outside it, then again it is returning empty array.

Comment: @AmandeepSachan Are you sure you follow my sample code? I send json when all async functions done

Comment: Thank you sir.. i was missing something else that was responsible for wrong result..